# Error with AppleUSB20XHCIPort on iOS El Capitan

Tags: ios, usb

I have a error with iOS El Capitan, the EndPoint 0x00 or 0x01 for Write not exists...

Kernel Log with connect my device on USB Port:

```
kernel[0]: 076526.463203 HS02@14200000: AppleUSB20XHCIPort::resetAndCreateDevice: failed to create device, disabling port
```

USB Device information:

```
Length:18
DescriptorType:Device
BcdUsb:0x0200
Class:PerInterface
SubClass:0x00
Protocol:0x00
MaxPacketSize0:16
VendorID:0x07C5
ProductID:0x0500
BcdDevice:0x0346
ManufacturerStringIndex:1
ProductStringIndex:2
SerialStringIndex:3
ConfigurationCount:1
ManufacturerString:?
ProductString:?
SerialString:?

CONFIG #1
Length:9
DescriptorType:Configuration
TotalLength:34
InterfaceCount:1
ConfigID:1
StringIndex:0
Attributes:0x80
MaxPower:250
ConfigString:

INTERFACE (0,0)
Length:9
DescriptorType:Interface
InterfaceID:0
AlternateID:0
EndpointCount:1
Class:Hid
SubClass:0x00
Protocol:0x00
StringIndex:0
InterfaceString:

ENDPOINT 0x81
Length:7
DescriptorType:Endpoint
EndpointID:0x81
Attributes:0x03
MaxPacketSize:8
Interval:100
Refresh:0
SynchAddress:0x00
```

When I try to use the Entry Point to send data, always get error System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Nothing has worked for me with the device.